# Array de valores en un CASE WHEN THEN de SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una vista que carga un listado de productos según los filtros de búsqueda establecidos por el usuario.

Como filtros, la búsqueda dispone de:

- un rango de fechas inicial y final.
- una lista de productos con opción de selección múltiple, es decir, poder marcar uno o varios productos, o ninguno.

La cuestión es que la lista de resultados tenga en cuenta el rango de fechas definido por el usuario así como si ha elegido o no alguno de los productos de la lista opcional como otro de los filtros a aplicar en el resultado de la búsqueda.

El número de productos es determinado, pongamos, para este ejemplo que son 8 productos.

Para este último criterio de filtrado, lo que se pretende es que, en la SQL relativa a la búsqueda, se tengan en cuenta todos y cada uno de los productos marcados en la lista múltiple y, si no se marcó ninguno, por defecto, que se consideren todos los productos.

Decir que al configurar el listado de opción múltiple, como dato interno que se envía al servidor, se considera el `Id_producto`, mientras que lo que se muestra al usuario es la descripción del producto, es decir, el campo `desc_producto`.

Entonces, en una consulta de ejemplo tengo lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @Fecha_ini VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Fecha_fin VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Fecha_ini_DT DATETIME
DECLARE @Fecha_fin_DT DATETIME
SET @Fecha_ini = '25-03-2018'
SET @Fecha_fin = '25-03-2019'
SET @Fecha_ini_DT = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONCAT(@Fecha_ini, ' 00:00:00'))
SET @Fecha_fin_DT = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONCAT(@Fecha_fin, ' 23:59:59'))
-- --------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @id_prod INTEGER
SET @id_prod = 796

--Con CONDICIONALES en el WHERE
SELECT *
FROM his_cal_plancontrol_res
INNER JOIN his_cal_plancontrol
    ON his_cal_plancontrol_res.Id_his_cal_plancontrol = his_cal_plancontrol.Id_his_cal_plancontrol
INNER JOIN his_of
    ON his_of.Cod_of = SUBSTRING(his_cal_plancontrol.Cod_cal_plancontrol, 1, 6)
INNER JOIN cfg_producto cp
    ON (cp.Id_producto = his_of.Id_producto)
INNER JOIN cfg_tipoproducto ctp
    ON (ctp.Id_tipoproducto = cp.Id_tipoproducto)
WHERE
    his_cal_plancontrol_res.fecha BETWEEN @Fecha_ini_DT AND @Fecha_fin_DT
    AND
        cp.Id_producto IN (
            CASE
                WHEN @id_prod IS NULL THEN
                    (796, 651,
                    1000, 749,
                    758, 990,
                    86, 792)
                ELSE
                    @id_prod
                END
        )
ORDER BY his_cal_plancontrol.Id_his_cal_plancontrol
```

Según los criterios de filtrado especificado por el usuario, lo que siempre va a llegar son la Fecha Inicial y la Fecha Final y por otro considerar el conjunto de productos marcados en la lista de opción múltiple.
Y, según lo que se marcó o no:
- habiendo marcado uno o varios productos, el conjunto o array de los marcados, se considere dentro del IN del WHERE de la SQL.
Pero, si no se llegase a marcar ninguno, se lleguen a considerar todos los IDs de los productos a considerar pasando un ARRAY de todos los IDs posibles en el THEN del CASE.
Pero al considerar esto, el ARRAY no es aceptado y da error.

Otra forma que intenté fue incluir un nuevo WHEN por cada valor de ID a tratar, tal como sigue, pero, entonces, solamente, me considera el primer WHEN y los demás no son considerados

```
SELECT *
FROM his_cal_plancontrol_res
INNER JOIN his_cal_plancontrol
    ON his_cal_plancontrol_res.Id_his_cal_plancontrol = his_cal_plancontrol.Id_his_cal_plancontrol
INNER JOIN his_of
    ON his_of.Cod_of = SUBSTRING(his_cal_plancontrol.Cod_cal_plancontrol, 1, 6)
INNER JOIN cfg_producto cp
    ON (cp.Id_producto = his_of.Id_producto)
INNER JOIN cfg_tipoproducto ctp
    ON (ctp.Id_tipoproducto = cp.Id_tipoproducto)
WHERE
    his_cal_plancontrol_res.fecha BETWEEN @Fecha_ini_DT AND @Fecha_fin_DT
    AND
        cp.Id_producto IN (
            CASE
                WHEN @id_prod IS NULL THEN 796
                WHEN @id_prod IS NULL THEN 651
                WHEN @id_prod IS NULL THEN 1000
                WHEN @id_prod IS NULL THEN 749
                WHEN @id_prod IS NULL THEN 758
                WHEN @id_prod IS NULL THEN 990
                WHEN @id_prod IS NULL THEN 86
                WHEN @id_prod IS NULL THEN 792
                ELSE
                    @id_prod
                END
        )
ORDER BY his_cal_plancontrol.Id_his_cal_plancontrol
```

Entonces, ¿cómo considerar todos los IDs de producto posible si el usuario no establece el filtro de producto y, por tanto, el parámetro llega como nulo o vacío?
Espero se haya entendido la cuestión que planteo. Gracias por las respuestas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que lo que quieres es que si no se selecciona un producto, entonces se seleccionen todos los valores posibles. Eso se hace comparando el parámetro con la columna y revisando si es nulo.

```
SELECT *
FROM his_cal_plancontrol_res
INNER JOIN his_cal_plancontrol
    ON his_cal_plancontrol_res.Id_his_cal_plancontrol = his_cal_plancontrol.Id_his_cal_plancontrol
INNER JOIN his_of
    ON his_of.Cod_of = SUBSTRING(his_cal_plancontrol.Cod_cal_plancontrol, 1, 6)
INNER JOIN cfg_producto cp
    ON (cp.Id_producto = his_of.Id_producto)
INNER JOIN cfg_tipoproducto ctp
    ON (ctp.Id_tipoproducto = cp.Id_tipoproducto)
WHERE
    his_cal_plancontrol_res.fecha BETWEEN @Fecha_ini_DT AND @Fecha_fin_DT
    AND
        (cp.Id_producto @id_prod OR @id_prod IS NULL )

ORDER BY his_cal_plancontrol.Id_his_cal_plancontrol
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Agrego la opción de `RECOMPILE` para que obtenga un plan óptimo, en vez de un plan seguro.

Si por el contrario, quieres limitar los productos a un listado preestablecido, puedes utilizar un método distinto.

```
SELECT *
FROM his_cal_plancontrol_res
INNER JOIN his_cal_plancontrol
    ON his_cal_plancontrol_res.Id_his_cal_plancontrol = his_cal_plancontrol.Id_his_cal_plancontrol
INNER JOIN his_of
    ON his_of.Cod_of = SUBSTRING(his_cal_plancontrol.Cod_cal_plancontrol, 1, 6)
INNER JOIN cfg_producto cp
    ON (cp.Id_producto = his_of.Id_producto)
INNER JOIN cfg_tipoproducto ctp
    ON (ctp.Id_tipoproducto = cp.Id_tipoproducto)
WHERE
    his_cal_plancontrol_res.fecha BETWEEN @Fecha_ini_DT AND @Fecha_fin_DT
    AND
        cp.Id_producto IN (
            SELECT prod
            FROM (VALUES(796),(651),(1000),(749),(758),(990),(86),(792))x(prod)
            WHERE @id_prod IS NULL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT @id_prod
        )
ORDER BY his_cal_plancontrol.Id_his_cal_plancontrol;
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @LuisCazares, ¿dónde se puede conseguir más información sobre `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`? En el manual de MySQL no consigo localizarlo :) ¿Con plan óptimo te refieres al EXPLAIN PLAN?

Comment: Para empezar, hay que definir el sistema que estás utilizando. Las etiquetas corresponden a SQL Server que es un producto de Microsoft. La sintaxis es distinta a la utilizada por MySQL. El código parece indicar que efectivamente es SQL Server. Puedes encontrar la referencia [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query)

Comment: Claro, con razón no encontraba nada en el manual de MySQL. Gracias @LuisCazares

Comment: Gracias @LuisCazares, me parece que me quedo con la segunda opción. No obstante, aunque entiendo el concepto de que lo que hace es elegir los valores especificados, ¿me puedes explicar algo más el cacho de `SELECT prod FROM (VALUES(796),(651),(1000),(749),(758),(990),(86),792))x(prod)`? sobre todo el `x(prod)`.

Comment: `x` es el alias de la tabla. `prod` es el nombre de la columna que contiene los valores. Al definir un constructor de tabla usando VALUES, no se tiene un nombre para las columnas. Por lo mismo, se tienen que definir junto con el alias de la tabla (la tabla también necesita un nombre).